# Вывести элементы массива 1ая буква которого стоит после Д

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив, допустим "вася", "дима", "леша", "наташа"

Нужно вывести только те элементы, 1 буква которых идет после "Д". То есть подходит только Леша и Наташа.

Прошу прощения, если задаю банальные вопросы, но решений слышал много и хочется знать самый быстрый.

Comment: решил задачу

Comment: решил-напиши ответ.Люди использовав поиск могут наткнутся на ваш вопрос и увидят ответ.

Comment: решение для прописных букв: http://pastebin.com/iFibLpQw

Comment: А зачем вам самый быстрый вариант? Они все примерно одинаковы по скорости. Если проблема в скорости, вероятно, php -- не ваш язык, пишите на чистом C или вообще на ассемблере.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте уж я тогда для народа озвучу..
1)берём первую букву
2)сравниваем её с "д"
3)ну и всё..

Comment: какие мы умные мммм

Comment: Я это написал, потому что вы своим решением не поделились.

Comment: @Александр Мироненко: ответ по сложности соответствует вопросу.